# Insert data in RichTextBox C#

Tags: c#

My code:

```
private void timer4_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
    {
        var infos = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")[a].GetAttribute("src");
        richTextBox1.Text = infos;
    }
    timer4.Stop();
}
```

I want to insert all of 10 src values in RichTextBox, while my code do it only once.

Comment: Well you're setting `richTextBox1.Text` to `infos`, ignoring the previous value. Perhaps you want `richTextBox1.AppendText(infos)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [AppendText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fzaza68(v=vs.110).aspx)

Replace

```
richTextBox1.Text = infos;
```

with

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(infos);
```

OR

```
richTextBox1.Text += infos + Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: `string.Concat` would probably be better than `string.Format` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong.

```
richTextBox1.Text = infos;
```

This is right.

```
richTextBox1.AppendText= infos;
```

Answer (score 0):

What your code is doing is setting the text to equal each `infos`, 10 times over.

So I'm guessing your output would be the last `infos` variable? What you might want to do instead is this:

```
private void timer4_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
    {
        var infos = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")[a].GetAttribute("src");
        richTextBox1.Text += infos; // the "+=" will add each infos to the textbox
    }
    timer4.Stop();
}
```

As you can see, if you use the `+=` instead of just `=`, it will add each iteration to the whole, instead of just overriding the *whole* value each time.